# Can't INSER timestamp into Postgresql psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm traying to inster timestamps as values in columns of my Postresql query but I seamn to get all sort of formating error in al variant ways is have tried this.

i have 3 cols that are timestamp : time_stamp,  start_date, end_date

```
start_date = datetime.strptime('2020-03-17 16:00:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timestamp()
end_date = datetime.strptime('2020-03-17 16:00:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timestamp()

sql_insert_query = 'INSERT INTO public.table(time_stamp, name, name_short, geo, link, img_url, source, type, category, start_date, end_date, quantity, remaining)' \
              ' VALUES ( current_timestamp, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s);'

insert_tuple = (item['name'],'name_short',item['language'],item['_url'],item['image_url'],'_API',item['coupon_type'],item['category'],start_date ,end_date,coupon_limits,item['unused'])

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(sql_insert_query, insert_tuple)
```

Error is (not exact as is translated):

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: the column «start_date» is of type timestamp without time zone but the expression is type numeric
```

on the SQL table i have declared columns as
    time_stamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    start_date timestamp without time zone,
    end_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,

Comment: `>>> type(datetime.now().timestamp())` returns `<class 'float'>` which clearly indicated by error message. Try to remove `.timestamp()`

Comment: Thanks this solved the issue